# How to read from Hive HDFS in spark 1.6?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I have a few tables in Hive in HDFS, how do I read them into dataframe from spark? How does HiveContext know where my hive warehouse is?

My current code, it throws out of memory error for some reason, these tables are tiny, 30k rows max, 3-5 columns.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hive Test").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(ctx);

// Queries are expressed in HiveQL.
DataFrame results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM departments");
results.show();


$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
Found 6 items
drwxrwxrwt   - [Omitted] hive          0 2016-10-30 14:09 /user/hive/warehouse/categories
drwxrwxrwt   - [Omitted] hive          0 2016-10-30 14:13 /user/hive/warehouse/customers
drwxrwxrwt   - [Omitted] hive          0 2016-10-30 14:09 /user/hive/warehouse/departments
drwxrwxrwt   - [Omitted] hive          0 2016-10-30 14:11 /user/hive/warehouse/order_items
drwxrwxrwt   - [Omitted] hive          0 2016-10-30 14:16 /user/hive/warehouse/orders
drwxrwxrwt   - [Omitted] hive          0 2016-10-30 14:09 /user/hive/warehouse/products




16/10/30 14:38:29 INFO ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.6.0
16/10/30 14:38:29 INFO ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.6.0
16/10/30 14:38:30 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
16/10/30 14:38:30 INFO ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
16/10/30 14:38:30 INFO Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
16/10/30 14:38:30 INFO Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
16/10/30 14:38:30 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/10/30 14:38:30 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/10/30 14:38:31 INFO ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Comment: Try `DataFrame results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM departments").limit(10);`

Comment: Same error, although I am seeing this


6/10/30 16:06:57 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException

Comment: @Instinct:  HiveContext will get the warehouse details from the `hive-site.xml` file available `conf` folder.

Comment: @Instinct: If  you are running this on local, you need to specify the warehouse location, what version of spark you are running.. If you are running Spark 2.0, you can specify `.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/IJava/")`

Comment: I am on version 1.6, i'll try both ways. Thank you

Comment: I just checked my config and hive-site.xml is set through cloudera CDH. I also tried sqlContext.setConf() like you said but I am still getting OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: I just switched to spark 2.0, and I think its working now. Is there a way I can specify a HDFS directory on local mode?